# CSS flex box with a fixed height still stretches

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a header with two columns that will fill to the parent container's height. I'm using `display:flex` for a responsive layout. When I set the header to have a fixed height, the two other sub-divs have a gap between them and the header.

```
div#container {
    padding:20px;
    background:#F1F1F1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    height:540px;
}
.header{width:100%; height:40px; background:#ccc;}
.content {
    width:150px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[image]

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9bM4/1118/)

**EDIT**

The *duplicate* question is a nice description of the flex properties, but I'm not seeing an example like this addressed in it.
If the `height:40px` is removed from the header, the header div will stretch down to the other divs. When the header height is specified, a gap exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`align-content` default value is `stretch`. Change that to `align-content: start;` and it should be okay.

```css
.content-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

div#container {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #F1F1F1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-content: start;
    height: 540px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header{width:100%; height:40px; background:#ccc;}
.content {
    width:150px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="header">
HEADER
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Title 1</h1>

        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Title 2</h1>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,...
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It aligns to the top, but doesn't stretch to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: @jim31415 in that case you need add a "content" wrapper. Updated the snippet.